# Change devices target of an .xcarchive

Tags: xcode, cocoonjs, xcarchive

I´m using Cocoon to build a Construct 2 project for IOS, specifically for iPhone.
The problem is that cocoon builds for "Universal" (iphone and iPad).
The build format is .xcarchive.

My question: How can I change the device target of a .xcarchive to let it run just in iPhones?